# Where can I find all App Maker button icons?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a list of button icons that can be used in App Maker? E.g. when you set the HTML text field of a button to 'Edit' and choose 'Icon' as button style, App Maker conveniently provides me an icon with a pencil on it.

Right now I'm looking for a dropdown arrow icon, but a list of icons would be so useful to make my UIs more clean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

App Maker uses material font:

https://material.io/icons/

Comment: I would not be that sure, that App Maker supports this icons superset...

Comment: Ok, I should've probably known how to look for those better, too. But I feel Google should also promote these kinds of things in App Maker more. Saving space and bringing in intuitiveness with icons (and other neat stuff) can really make an app in this case. Someone using App Maker might not have much time or knowledge to put into design, so these small things help, a lot. But this was great, thanks a ton !!

Comment: I hope App Maker has a way to import custom icons.

Comment: For future visitors, To be clear, the icons are just font. The word `delete` looks like  ️. You also must choose icon variant(top left).

Answer (score 0):

So it took me some time re-reading the comments and trying to understand how to do it. This is for future readers:

- Go to https://material.io/icons/ and in the search bar on left, type the icon you are looking for. e.g. I am looking for left arrow.
- Scroll the page down, and hover over the icon you are looking for and check the exact name of the icon. Copy it.
- On your page/page fragment/popup, click on Widgets icon on top left.
- Type button, and drag Button on your page (or fragment or popup).
- On top left, right beside the Widgets icon, click the drop down and select "Icon".
- Ensure your icon is selected on your page. In the property editor on the right,paste the exact name of the icon e.g. "keyboard_arrow_left".
- The button will update with the icon of your choice.

Hope it helps.