# Images on buttons? It must be easy

Tags: google-app-maker

It seems a very simple requirement.
How do I put an image on a button? The delete button has a style variant of Icon, but I can't see where the image is coming from.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[Where can I find all App Maker button icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903106/where-can-i-find-all-app-maker-button-icons) ...partially solved my problem, in that I can see the text value is used to find the icon resource, but I would like to know how to put my own image on a button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find all App Maker button icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903106/where-can-i-find-all-app-maker-button-icons)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use an image file of your own, you can insert it as an Image widget, and then use the onClick event for the image to set the button's action.

With that said, I am a huge fan of the Material icon set that's linked from the [Where can I find all App Maker button icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903106/where-can-i-find-all-app-maker-button-icons) question. I can pretty much always find an icon that works for what I need; then it's just a matter of setting the button style to Icon and using the name of the icon as the button text.